# AngularJS ui-view nested routes with url parameters on parent

Tags: angularjs, routes, uiview, url-parameters

I'm trying to use angular ui-router in my project and I'm running into an issue about maintaining url parameters in the parent route while adding child ones...

I have a settings page with the following route: /settings/:messageCode/:status

And now I need to add a piece of template that changes depending on the route so the new display looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9BqH.jpg

```html
<div>
   <div id="sidebar">...</div>
   <div id="topbar">...</div>

   <div ui-view>
      <!-- This is the variable content depending on the route -->
   </div>

</div>
```

The new routes I need to add are the following:

- /settings/studio
- /settings/payments

And this is my code for the nested routing

```js
...
$stateProvider
   .state("register", {...})
   .state("settings", {
        url: "/settings", // the objective is to keep the previous route "/status/:messageCode/:status"
        templateUrl: 'settings/settings.view.html',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl as vm',
        params: {
          messageCode: {
            value: null,
            squash: true,
            dynamic: true,
          },
          success: {
            value: null,
            squash: true,
          },
   })
   .state("settings.studio", {
        url: "/studio",
        templateUrl: 'template-tab-studio.html',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl as vm',
   })
   .state("settings.payments", {
        url: "/payments",
        templateUrl: 'template-tab-payments.html',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl as vm',
   })
```

At the moment, the routing is working fine, but I lost the URL params on the parent component (settings home), while adding its new children without having to add the url parameters to all childrens.

The problem of having to add the URL params to all children, is that I'll need to add many more views, so having to maintain all that routes will complicate things.

**Is there a way to keep the original route in the parent (/settings/:messageCode/:status) while adding children so they can also recieve that paremeters?**

Target routes would look like this: /settings/{dinamicView}/:messageCode/:status.

Answer (score 0):

can't get what parameters do you mean, to pass variables to child route you could use **resolve**

to keep previous route change url: "/settings" to url: "settings"